# Dependency service event

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am trying to call the event handler from droid side, however it doesn't get fired. everyone else works however this event doesn't get fired. I am not sure what am I doing wrong. I have my dependency service registered at MainActivity and set dependency in my service.

```cs
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
  DocumentResults results;
  IScanService scanService;
  
  public MainPage()
  {
      InitializeComponent();
      results = new DocumentResults();
      BindingContext = new MainPageViewModel();
      System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("test cw");
      Console.WriteLine("test cw");
         scanService = DependencyService.Get<IScanService>();
     scanService.ResultsParsedEvent += (s, ev) => { ResultsParsed(null, ev); };
  }

  void Button_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
  {
    scanService.ScanService();

    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(test))
    {
      scanService.Parsing(test);
    }
  }

  private void ResultsParsed(DocumentResults results,EventArgs e)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("update ");
    testLbl.Text = results.Name;
  }
}
```

My interface

```cs
public interface IScanService
{
  event EventHandler ResultsParsedEvent;

  string ScanService(); 

  void Parsing(string test);

  void resultsParsed(DocumentResults results, EventArgs e);
}
```

Droid implementation

```cs
public class RegService : IScanService
{
  public event EventHandler ResultsParsedEvent;
  DocumentResults results;
  public string Test;
  
  public String ScanService()
  {
    Test = "scan";
    return Test;
  }

  public void Parsing(string test)
  {
    Test = "parsing";
    var results= new DocumentResults();
    results.Name = Test;
    Thread thread1 = new Thread(() => resultsParsed(results,null));

    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
    resultsParsed(results,null);
  }

  public void resultsParsed(DocumentResults results, EventArgs e)
  {
    ResultsParsedEvent?.Invoke(results, e);
  }
}
```

Comment: this is the same issue I commented on in your last question.  You are creating a **new instance** of your service every time you call `Get`.  You need to do this **once** and maintain a reference to it instead of creating a new instance each time.

Comment: var service = DependencyService.Get<IScanService>();
             string test = service.ScanService(); like this?

Comment: please see my updated question, now I am getting null reference

Comment: now I am getting null reference and when I debug I am going directly to private void ResultsParsed(DocumentResults results,EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("update ");
            testLbl.Text = results.Name;
        }

Comment: `scanService.ResultsParsedEvent += (s, ev) => { ResultsParsed(**null**, ev); };`

Comment: still the result in MainPage is null, but thank you for your help.

Comment: is the event handler actually being called now?

Comment: yes, it is being called

Comment: OK, so that solves the problem you actually posted about.  Did you fix the hardcoded null reference I mentioned earlier?

Comment: yes, the problem is solved and I fixed the null. I you post it as answer I can accept it